# Генерировать меню любой вложенности yii2

Tags: php, yii2, nested-sets

Всем доброго времени суток. Начал осваивать yii2, есть задача сгенерировать меню в виде дерева и заполнить его произвольными данными. Чтоб получилось типа такого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меню может быть из пяти, шести, семи узлов. То есть количество узлов я указываю при генерации. Алгоритм построения дерева - Nested Sets. То есть я указываю количество узлов и уже сгенерированное меню инсертится в БД по принципу Nested Sets.
Подскажите пожалуйста как проще в yii2 выполнить такую задачку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Массив с данными:

```
    [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["parent_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Sportswear"
    ["keywords"]=>
    NULL
    ["description"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["parent_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Mens"
    ["keywords"]=>
    NULL
    ["description"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["parent_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Womens"
    ["keywords"]=>
    NULL
    ["description"]=>
    NULL
  }
```

Функция для генерации дерева:

```
protected function getTree(){
    $tree = [];
    foreach ($this->data as $id=>&$node) {
        if (!$node['parent_id']) {
            $tree[$id] = &$node;
        } else {
            $this->data[$node['parent_id']]['childs'][$node['id']] = &$node;
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое, на мой взгляд это сформировать массив с категориями и рекурсивно пробегать по нему. Например:

```
$data = [
            [
                'name' => 'Автомобили',
                'children' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'Мазда',
                        'children' => [
                            [
                                'name' => 'Мазда 3',
                            ],
                            [
                                'name' => 'Мазда 6'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Мотоциклы',
                'children' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'Кавасаки',
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'Харлей',
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];

function createTreeExample($data, $parent = null) {
        foreach ($data as $item) {
            $category = new Category(['name' => $item['name']]);
            if(!isset($parent)) {
                $category->makeRoot();
            } else {
                $category->appendTo($parent);
            }
            if (!empty($item['children'])) {
                $this->createTreeExample($item['children'], $category);
            }
        }
    }
```

Методы **makeRoot()** и **appendTo()** из расширения [yii2-nested-sets](https://github.com/creocoder/yii2-nested-sets)